# getting a significant offset from file.tell() using iterators

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

Looking at **file.tell()**, I was expecting it to give me a position that I could use with **file.seek()**.  But I am unsure how to do that in practice, since tell() seems to point me to the end of the file from the start.

Here's some test data:

```
i am line 1
i am line 2
i am line 3
```

And the program:

```
with open("./test_tell.txt") as fi:
    for line in fi:
        seekto = fi.tell()
        print "position:%d" % fi.tell()
        print(line)

    #we're at the end
    fi.seek(seekto)
    print("seekto:%s" % fi.read())

    fi.seek(seekto-5)
    print("seekto-5:%s" % fi.read())
```

output:

```
position:35
i am line 1

position:35
i am line 2

position:35
i am line 3
seekto:
seekto-5:ine 3
```

Notice how I get to 35, end of file, right from the beginning?  How can I cause the iterator to only advance to the end of each line as it goes, so that `tell` is actually useful to know where I am in the file?  I am sensing that the whole file is read as an optimization, which is why tell puts me right at the end.

The reason I care is that I am working on a state machine based program that runs through a big file.  For debugging purposes, I'd like to present a window of *n-lines back, current line and n-lines ahead*.  Was hoping to seek using the tell position to read ahead with a different file open of the same file.  That's not working since tell always points to the end.

Python 2.7, in case the file semantics have changed.

Comment: I/O is buffered so `ftell` can give wrong results.

Comment: doesn't work in python 3: mixing file iterators & ftell doesn't work.

Comment: and even opening non-buffered, `open("./test_tell.txt", "r", 0)`, or line-by-line buffering, `open("./test_tell.txt", "r", 1)`, doesn't work?  it didn't when I tried it in any case, still 35 across the board.

Comment: How do you expect to get the number of lines *ahead* without reading all the eol characters first? But anyway: why don't you just keep a count of the *bytes* read, if you want to know the current position?

Comment: @ekhumoro   not sure what you meant by the first bit - as stated, I was going to do a second file open and seek to the current position and then readline a bit ahead.  As to your suggestion - yes, I agree it would work if I did the bookkeeping myself, but... `tell` seemed to fit my use case.  This is just for debugging.  And a bit of curiosity  - most unusual to catch Python code behaving in unexpected fashion though I get how the buffering is causing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your example doesn't trigger an error with Python 2, but fails because reading with iterator is *buffered* probably for performance reasons.

Most of the time, when you're reading line by line, you don't care about the file position (more generally: you don't care about the file position in a text file)

So the file is read in 1 operation, leaving you with the end offset of the file.

note that Python 3 is more strict: you get an exception by using `tell` after having iterated on the line.

```
OSError: telling position disabled by next() call
```

One way to do it would be

- open the file in *binary* mode (Windows, else, you'll have shifts because of carriage return chars)
- read & compute position by adding the length of the current line

my code: works in python 2 & python 3 (where decoding is required to get rid of the bytes representation to do it better):

```
with open("./text.txt","rb") as fi:
    current_offset = 0
    line_pos=[]
    for line in fi:
        line_pos.append(current_offset)
        current_offset += len(line)
        print(line)

    fi.seek(line_pos[1])
    print("seekto:%s" % next(fi))
```

result:

```
b'i am line 1\r\n'
b'i am line 2\r\n'
b'i am line 3\r\n'
seekto:b'i am line 2\r\n'
```

note that I successfully seeked on the start of the second line so `next(fi)` read the second line.

Of course, it's still possible to store the lines in a `list`, unless it's too big, in which case this method has some interest (that is: if the file is not written back by another process, else the line offsets info needs updating)

Comment: Worked very well, txs.  Because all I care about is the current offset, `current_offset += len(line)` was sufficient.  Not sure how useful this is for real code, but being able to get a sense of the surrounding data in a big file during troubleshooting is nice.