# What's a more efficient Pythonic method to read a file line-by-line while tracking line offsets for future reference?

Tags: python, io

I want to read a file line-by-line, noting the file offset of each line so I can go back to it later.

I'm doing it manually like this:

```
while True:
    offset = ifile.tell()
    line = ifile.readline()
    if not line: break
    ...
```

but it looks clumsy and seems to be quite slow. Is there a better, more pythonic way to do this?

Comment: I don’t see why this is clumsy or slow. Practically any method of iterating over lines will ultimately call readline() in a loop; tell()’s cost should be quite low compared with readline() and I/O in general. It sounds like you might be optimizing prematurely.

Comment: I had this issue a long time ago.  Seems like `tell` isn't all that reliable in text mode, due to buffering (this was on 2.7, but was flagged as also unlikely to work on 3).  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46716840/1394353.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as file:
    Lines = file.readlines()
        
count = 0
for line in Lines:
    count += 1
    print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the file object as an iterator:

```
def find_page_offsets(fname):
    page_offsets = []
    offset = 0
    with open(fname, 'rb') as fobj:
        for line in fobj:
            if line.startswith(b'%%Page:'):
                page_offsets.append(offset)
            offset += len(line)
    return page_offsets
```

Note that `fobj.tell()`does not work in the loop. Therefore, you need use `len(line)` and add this to the `offset`. Also, you need to open the file in binary mode to avoid automatic line ending conversion on Windows.

Comment: `fobj.tell()` seems to work just fine for me inside the loop. @prabu naresh's code below is nearly line-for-line identical to what I wound up writing. I realize that there are some tricky issues with file offsets when working with utf-8 and Windows line endings, but I'm only grabbing the file offset at the start of lines and using that value to go back to the same point in the file, and so far it's worked out just fine.

Comment: Oh, wait. You're referring to `tell()` not playing well with file iterators. I've seen that mentioned elsewhere. Luckily for me, I'm not using an iterator in this case.

Comment: Did you check the run times of the iterator approach and the `while True` loop for your use case? The iterator is often considerably faster for my use cases.

Comment: I haven't timed it, but it *feels* slower to do the loop instead of the iterator; which is why I was hoping there was a solution using the iterator. That said, "feels slower" is no data at all, so I honestly don't know if it's slower. I suppose I should actually test it.

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('your_file.ps', 'r') as ifile:
    page_offsets = []
    while True:
        offset = ifile.tell()
        line = ifile.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        if line.startswith(b'%%Page:'):
            page_offsets.append(offset)

# Now 'page_offsets' contains the file offsets of each %%Page: directive
```

Comment: I think `enumerate()` returns the line number. I was hoping for the actual file offset. The idea is that I'm processing a postscript file, and making a note of the location of each `%%Page:` directive so I can seek back to them later.

Comment: If you need to get the actual file offset instead of the line number, you can achieve this using the tell() method of the file object. refer the edited code above

Comment: This is just the same code as the OP posted; what’s the value of this answer?